# Order Factored Time Series Data

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

I have a dataset like the following:

```
a <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="Time Counter Speed
7:55:00    CT08W 63.79
9:30:00    CT08W 67.69
7:05:00    CT11W 68.34
8:40:00    CT10W 68.39
11:00:00    CT11W 68.00
10:40:00    CT01W 21.57
11:35:00    CT02W 72.03
5:25:00    CT12W 66.93
6:10:00    CT02W 62.79
12:05:00    CT02W 71.79                   ")
a 
        Time Counter Speed
1   7:55:00   CT08W 63.79
2   9:30:00   CT08W 67.69
3   7:05:00   CT11W 68.34
4   8:40:00   CT10W 68.39
5  11:00:00   CT11W 68.00
6  10:40:00   CT01W 21.57
7  11:35:00   CT02W 72.03
8   5:25:00   CT12W 66.93
9   6:10:00   CT02W 62.79
10 12:05:00   CT02W 71.79

str(a)
'data.frame':   10 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Time   : Factor w/ 10 levels "10:40:00","11:00:00",..: 8 10 7 9 2 1 3 5 6 4
 $ Counter: Factor w/ 6 levels "CT01W","CT02W",..: 3 3 5 4 5 1 2 6 2 2
 $ Speed  : num  63.8 67.7 68.3 68.4 68 ...
```

I don't want to use `as.POSIXct` in the solution as it involves difficulties while annotating the figure.

```
ggplot(a, aes(x=Time, y=Counter, fill=Speed))
```

[image]

The plot shows that time is ordered wrongly. Is there a way to order the time while it is factored?

Comment: First, you need to coerce the variable to a date/time format. Currently it's factor, which means the order is as printed with `levels(a$TIME_CNTR)`.

Comment: I mentioned that I want to avoid date/time format as this problem requires lots of annotation in the plot, which is difficult to handle in date/time format plots. I am thinking of a pseudo ordering for the factored time stamps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the a date-time format for your time variable to order your factor.

The key is using the date-time variable to do the sorting, which can be done a variety of ways.  Here, I create a date-time variable and sort it when making the factor variable.

```
a$dt = as.POSIXct(a$Time, format = "%H:%M:%S")

a$Time2 = factor(format(a$dt, "%H:%M:%S"), levels = format(sort(a$dt), "%H:%M:%S"))
a$Time2
[1] 07:55:00 09:30:00 07:05:00 08:40:00 11:00:00 10:40:00 11:35:00 05:25:00 06:10:00 12:05:00
Levels: 05:25:00 06:10:00 07:05:00 07:55:00 08:40:00 09:30:00 10:40:00 11:00:00 11:35:00 12:05:00

ggplot(a, aes(x=Time2, y=Counter, fill=Speed))
```

[image]

If using this method and the times aren't unique, you'll need to add `unique` into the `levels` argument.

Answer (score 1):

```
a$Time <- factor(a$Time, levels = a$Time[order(as.POSIXct(a$Time, format = "%H:%M:%S"))])
ggplot(a, aes(x=Time, y=Counter, fill=Speed))
```